# 'Authority of Incumbent ' what does this phrase mean in Job description analysis

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, marketing, management

'Authority of incumbent' in job description

**Job description**
A job description is a written statement of what the jobholder actually does, how he or she does it, and under what conditions the job is performed. There is no standard format for writing job descriptions, but most descriptions include sections on:
•   job identification
•   job summary
•   relationships, responsibilities, and duties
•   authority of incumbent
•   standards of performance
•   working conditions
•   job specifications

Comment: It means, basically, what processes and people the person who holds the job title has authority over.

Comment: @Robusto thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "that one to whom authority has been conferred" or (synonymously) "that one who has been entrusted with the authority" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/incumbent_1?q=incumbent)).

Here, it means simply "the authority of the person who will be hired", "authority of the person who will be entrusted with the responsability that the job entails".

Comment: For example, the incumbent might have the authority to hire and fire people, or to authorise payments of up to 1 million Euros, etc.